# Need keyboard on double tap and not on single tap

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

I don't want to show the keyboard on single click on the textfield, rather I want to show it on double click.
For this I created two actions, one for single tap and other for double tap and also used textfield delegate method:

```
            [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];   // for double tap
            [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];   // for single tap

METHOD DEFINATION:

-(void)clicked    // action for double tap
{
    count=2;
     NSLog(@"--------double------%d",count);
    [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)clicked1   //action for single tap

{
    count=1;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  //textfield delegate
{
if(count==1)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
}
```

This code is working fine but not always. Sometimes "UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat" event is not detected and the "clicked" function doesn't work.
I am unable to understand the reason, that why the event is not working every time.

Comment: reedit your question don't ask for same question by different post

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this one.

```
//Tap GestureRecognizer to recognize tap
     UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(youMethodName)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

//use yourMethodName to show keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Dont add any action for textfield 
do like below

```
   @interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
    {
      int count;
    }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     count = 0;//initially put zero
     self.textField.delegate = self; //textfield added in xib or story board

   }

   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
      count++;
      if(count == 2)
      {
        count = 0;
        return YES;
      }

     if(count >= 2)
     count = 0;
     return NO;

 }

 //for testing i am doing like this
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
  }
```